# ¿Cómo incluir una función SQL dentro de procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Estoy desarrollando un procedimiento almacenado en SqlServer 2005,donde se pasa una lista de enteros separados por coma para realizar una selección de registros

algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE status  IN (@Parametro)ORDER BY status;
```

Pude solucionar con una función y ejecutándola dentro del procedimiento almacenado, pero por razones de seguridad no puedo instalar la función…así que debo incluir el  código de la función dentro del procedimiento almacenado...

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Codigo de la Funcion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIntInList] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END
```

Codigo del SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ObtenerPrestamo] 
(
     @Parametro VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT A.Id_Bp_Sap , 
       A.Titular_Nombre , 
       A.Titular_DocumentoTipo , 
       A.Titular_DocumentoNumero , 
       A.preFecha, 
       A.preMontoAAcreditar,
       A.preMontoFinanciar , 
       A.preId,
       A.linid FROM Prestamos AS A  INNER JOIN Lineas AS B 
       ON A.linid = B.linid 
       WHERE A.estId IN (SELECT number FROM GetIntInList(@Parametro)) AND A.preNroCtaDebito <> 0

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadir al procedure el parámetro lista.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ObtenerPrestamo] 
(
 @Parametro VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @X XML;
DECLARE @Separador varchar(1)= ',';
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table (numParameter Int Identity(1,1), value varchar(100))


SELECT @X = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + REPLACE(@Parametro , @Separador, '</s><s>') +  '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
       FROM @X.nodes('/r/s') T(c);


SELECT A.Id_Bp_Sap , 
       A.Titular_Nombre , 
       A.Titular_DocumentoTipo , 
       A.Titular_DocumentoNumero , 
       A.preFecha, 
       A.preMontoAAcreditar,
       A.preMontoFinanciar , 
       A.preId,
       A.linid 
   FROM Prestamos AS A  INNER JOIN Lineas AS B 
        ON A.linid = B.linid 
   INNER JOIN @TablaParametros T 
        ON A.estId = T.value;
   WHERE  A.preNroCtaDebito <> 0

END;
```

Separas los parámetros recibidos con xml:

```
Declare @Parametro nvarchar(max) = '1,2,5,12'
DECLARE @X XML;
DECLARE @Separador varchar(1)= ',';
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table (numParameter Int Identity(1,1), value varchar(100))
SELECT @X = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + REPLACE(@Parametro , @Separador, '</s><s>') + '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @TablaParametros 
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
       FROM @X.nodes('/r/s') T(c);

SELECT * FROM @TablaParametros
```

[image: Resultado del ejemplo]

Luego solo tienes que hacer un inner join contra tú conjunto a y solo te devolverá estos registros.

Comment: Hola y gracias Javi fer2 ... Lo unico que no entiendo bien que datos le voy a pasar al parametro @list ??

Comment: La función recibía como parámetro una lista de enteros separados por comas. Y te devolvía esa lista en una tabla, la cual utilizabas como criterio para incluir solo los resultados que no estuvieran en ese resultado. Y solo hace falta uno. Lo leí en los dos sitios, y estaba pensando en dos parámetros. Ahora te edito la respuesta para que quede como tiene que ser.

Comment: Ok ...Muchas Gracias funciono perfecto

Comment: @Javifer2 Tanto la pregunta como la respuesta son muy interesantes. ¿Sería posible postear una generalización, comentada, del mecanismo que pueda orientar a personas con necesidades afines?

Comment: @quevedo Si claro. Cuando tenga un ratito lo realizo.

Comment: @quevedo He incluido un post más detallado de diferentes maneras de realizar lo solicitado. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334247/pasar-una-cadena-de-texto-a-un-procedure-para-obtener-datos-cuyos-valores-est%c3%a9n/334248#334248

Comment: Muchas gracias. Hiciste un gran trabajo