# Pasar una cadena de texto a un procedure, para obtener datos cuyos valores estén comprendidos entre los elementos de la cadena

Tags: sql-server

A menudo necesitamos pasar a un procedimiento almacenado una cadena de texto que contenga una lista de elementos para poder obtener una información filtrada. 
¿Cómo solucionarlo?

```
Create Table dbo.Spices
([id]    int identity(1, 1) Primary Key, 
 [col1]  varchar(100), 
 [col2]  varchar(100), 
 [col3]  varchar(100), 
 [fecha] datetime2 default(getdate())
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Spices (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
('1AB1', 'Hebras',  'Azafrán'   ),
('1A21', 'Grano',   'Pimienta'  ),
('1CC1', 'Grano',   'Achiote'   ),
('2AB1', 'Grano',   'Anís'      ),
('3AB3', 'Rama',    'Azafrán'   ),
('1DAB', 'Polvo',   'Apio'      ),
('1AB4', 'Rama',    'Canela'    ),
('3AB4', 'Grano',   'Cardamomo' ),
('1AB4', 'Vaina',   'Vainilla'  ),
('2AB4', 'Pétalos', 'Cártamo'   ),
('BAB4', 'Polvo',   'Cilantro'  ),
('1AB4', 'Polvo',   'Cebolla'   ),
('5AB4', 'Grano',   'Clavo'     ),
('2AB4', 'Grano',   'Comino'    ),
('BAB4', 'Polvo',   'Cúrcuma'   ),
('6AB4', 'Hoja',    'Enebro'    ),
('7AB4', 'Semillas','Eneldo'    ),
('8AB4', 'Raíz',    'Equinácea' ),
('9AB4', 'Hoja',    'Estragon'  ),
('2CB3', 'Semillas','Hinojo'    );
GO
```

La necesidad es obtener los diferentes registros de cada uno de los tipos definidos en col2. Con un procedimiento almacenado que reciba un varchar como parámetro.

Una de las posibles variantes de salida, ya que esto vendrá determinado por los parámetros, puede ser:

```
Exec dbo.GetSpicesXml 
   @spices = 'Hoja@@Polvo'
 , @splitSep = '@@';

6           1DAB  Polvo   Apio       2020-03-01
11          BAB4  Polvo   Cilantro   2020-03-01
12          1AB4  Polvo   Cebolla    2020-03-01
15          BAB4  Polvo   Cúrcuma    2020-03-01
16          6AB4  Hoja    Enebro     2020-03-01
19          9AB4  Hoja    Estragon   2020-03-01
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask], a tu pregunta le falta estructura

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación. Este post lo he abierto a petición de otro usuario, que me solició en un comentario anterior, una generalización de como realizar lo que indica la pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327985/c%c3%b3mo-incluir-una-funci%c3%b3n-sql-dentro-de-procedimiento-almacenado/328003#328003

Comment: Un ejemplo de tu pa, describir mejor el escenario, una muestra de los datos de entrada y salida ayudaría a mejorar su calidad

Comment: @Aprendiz Yo le sugerí a OP hacer una generalización de una respuesta que me pareció muy útil, pensando que puede ayudar a muchas personas. Y, el invirtió bastante tiempo en preparar este post, que, en combinación con las respuestas ofrecidas, es excelente.

Comment: Lo sé @quevedo jamás mencioné que no sirva, lo que si le comenté es que la pregunta necesitaba mas trabajo, pues al inicio era un tanto escueta... estodo

Comment: @Aprendiz no cuestiono tu comentario, hago una aclaración, porque de una respuesta a una pregunta muy particular, surgió una generalización muy útil. Y, el camino hasta acá fue tortuoso y, es seguro, que en el momento en que comentaste la pregunta era pobre y mal formulada. Ahora, no es el caso gracias a su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este escenario, en principio tenemos dos dificultades identificables.

La primera es separar los valores que recibimos, en valores independientes.

La segunda, es como mezclar del modo eficiente, o con un código limpio, estos elementos para obtener las filas que disponen de información que encaja, con los valores recibidos como parámetros.

Opción 1. **Alternativa xml con Inner join**

Utilizando un tipo de dato xml y una variable de tipo tabla, que podemos mezclar con Inner Join para obtener los datos de nuestra tabla de origen.

Nota: Aunque utilizo varchar y de un tamaño de 1000, es completamente adaptable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpicesXML
(
    @Spices  Varchar(1000),
    @SplitSep Varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
( 
  numParameter Int Identity(1,1)
, value varchar(100)
)

--  Solución para dificultad 1
SELECT @Xml = 
CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
  REPLACE(@Spices , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') +  '</s></r>');

INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) 
        AS Value
       FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);
--  Con los parámetros separados.
SELECT [id]
     , [col1]
     , [col2]
     , [col3]
     , [fecha]
FROM 
     dbo.Spices 
     INNER JOIN @TablaParametros T on Spices.col2 = T.value
--  Solución para dificultad 2
END
GO
```

En la variable de tabla @TablaParametros, tenemos la lista de elementos que recibimos en el varchar @Spices y utilizamos como elemento separador lo que recibimos en @SplitSep.

La ejecución del procedure, puede ser tal que:

```
Exec dbo.GetSpicesXml 
   @spices = 'Hoja@@Polvo'
 , @splitSep = '@@';
-- O
Exec dbo.GetSpicesXml 'Hoja@@Polvo','@@';
```

Opción 2: **Alternativa Xml con Cross Apply**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpicesXML
(
    @Spices  Varchar(1000),
    @SplitSep Varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
(
 numParameter Int Identity(1,1), 
 value varchar(100)
);
--  Solución para dificultad 1
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@Spices , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
     'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
   FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);


SELECT [id]
     , [col1]
     , [col2]
     , [col3]
     , [fecha]
FROM 
     dbo.Spices 
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.VALUE 
      FROM @TablaParametros T 
      WHERE T.VALUE = Spices.col2) fn
--  Solución para dificultad 2

END
GO
```

Con el operador Apply, queda un código muy limpio, y aunque en este tipo de ejemplo, su rendimiento no va a ser mejor que inner join, es una alternativa a tener en cuenta, cuando las consultas son más complejas.

Opción 3: **Alternativa Xml con el operador lógico IN**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpicesXML
(
    @Spices  Varchar(1000),
    @SplitSep Varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
(
  numParameter Int Identity(1,1), 
  value varchar(100)
);

SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@Spices , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
         'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
        FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);
--  Solución para dificultad 1


SELECT [id]
     , [col1]
     , [col2]
     , [col3]
     , [fecha]
FROM 
     dbo.Spices s
    where s.col2 in 
    (
        Select value 
        from @TablaParametros t
    )
 -- Solución para dificultad 2

END
GO
```

El uso de In hace que la consulta sea muy fácilmente identificable y probablemente obtenga un rendimiento excelente, si la lista de valores no es demasiado grande.

Opción 4: **Alternativa Xml con el operador Exists**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpicesXML
(
    @Spices  Varchar(1000),
    @SplitSep Varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
(
    numParameter Int Identity(1,1), 
    value varchar(100)
);

 SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
 REPLACE(@Spices , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
     '</s></r>');
 INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
             'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
        FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);
 -- Solución para dificultad 1


SELECT [id]
     , [col1]
     , [col2]
     , [col3]
     , [fecha]
FROM 
     dbo.Spices  s
       where exists
        (
           Select value 
              from @TablaParametros t
              where t.value = s.col2
        )
  --    Solución para dificultad 2

 END
GO
```

La utilización del operador exists, en muchos escenarios será idéntico que el operador IN.

Ya hemos visto cuatro maneras diferentes de mezclar ambos conjuntos. Con Inner Join, con Cross Apply, con In, con Exists

Una mejora si el rendimiento no es suficientemente bueno, puede ser utilizar una tabla temporal, y una vez insertados los valores, ejecutar la actualización de las estadísticas.

Opción 5: **Mejora Rendimiento**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpicesXML
(
    @Spices  Varchar(1000),
    @SplitSep Varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Xml XML;
Create Table #TablaParametros
(
   numParameter Int Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
   value varchar(100)
);

SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@Spices , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO #TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
          'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
       FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);

UPDATE STATISTICS #TablaParametros
--  Solución para dificultad 1, si el rendimiento no es bueno.


 SELECT [id]
      , [col1]
      , [col2]
      , [col3]
      , [fecha]
 FROM 
      dbo.Spices  s
          where exists
            (
            Select value 
                from #TablaParametros t
                where t.value = s.col2
            )
  --    Solución para dificultad 2

 END
GO
```

Para el problema 1 de separar los elementos que recibimos como parámetros, existen multitud de soluciones. Puedes aplicar varias diferentes, que puedes leer en este artículo con más detalle.

[Pasar Lista de valores a un procedure](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/pasar-lista-de-valores-a-un-procedure/)

Comment: Muy completo!, gracias. Voy a probarlo.