# Reporting Services error parámetros multivaluados al especificar "(campo IN (@param ) OR @param IS NULL)" en la query

Tags: sql-server, parametros, ssrs

Estoy utilizando un shared dataset en un informe de SSRS 2008, y en este dataset he definido la consulta como texto. Como la consulta es muy lenta, he añadido varios parámetros (tipo numérico) de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM VistaCoches
WHERE (CódigoMarca IN (@CódigoMarca) OR @CódigoMarca IS NULL)
AND (CódigoGrupo IN (@CódigoGrupo) OR @CódigoGrupo IS NULL)
AND (CódigoModelo IN (@CódigoModelo) OR @CódigoModelo IS NULL)
```

Esto me permite ejecutar la consulta sin tener que especificar esos parámetros, y funciona bien para parámetros de un solo valor (como una fecha) pero cuando quiero poder asignar varios valores al parámetro para filtrar el informe, me devuelve este error:

> Error al procesar el informe. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Error de ejecución del conjunto de datos compartido 'Coches'.(rsDataSetExecutionError)
>   Error de ejecución de consulta para el conjunto de datos 'DataSet1'.(rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   Para obtener más información acerca de este error, vaya al servidor de informes en el equipo del servidor local o habilite los errores remotos.

Este problema se extrapola a otros informes y conjuntos que tengo. Quizás deba indicar que los campos por los que se filtran los parámetros nunca son nulos, pero necesito poder omitir el filtrado de esos campos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿En lugar de `IN` no deberías usar `=`, algo así: ... `WHERE (CódigoMarca = @CódigoMarca OR @CódigoMarca IS NULL)` ... ?

Comment: No, porque tengo entendido que el parámetro puede ser una lista de valores.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415629/5587982) y los enlaces que hay allí. Leyendo que intentas responder con esto a un problema de lentitud en las consultas, quizá debas verificar la causa de esa lentitud y resolver el problema a otro nivel (índices, tipo de datos, modelo de datos, lógica que estás implementando para filtrar los datos, ...).

Comment: Esto es algo que usamos para el problema de lentitud, pero aparte de eso, en algunos de los conjuntos, se usa por necesidad. En algunos casos de los que tenemos podría sustituirlo si encuentro otra solución, pero en otros conjuntos de datos es necesario tener un parámetro opcional que permita múltiples valores para filtrar el informe.

Answer (score 0):

No se si la opción que te voy a presentar será válida para la ejecución utilizando un shared dataset en un informe de SSRS 2008, o te presentará algún tipo de problema. Pero lo que tengo claro, es que una lista de valores no es un IN.

```
declare @table table (id varchar (10))
insert into @table (id)
values
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('4');
-- Esto es funcional
select * from @table
where id in ('1','3');
-- Pero esto no. Hay que separar los valores, para que sea un elemento de cada.
select * from @table 
where id in ('1,3');
go
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la columna es numérica, igual de mal

```
declare @table table (id int)
insert into @table (id)
values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);
select * from @table
where id in (1,3);
-- Esta opción genera una excepción, porque no la puede convertir a un int
select * from @table 
where id in ('1,3');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder utilizar una lista de valores en un rango, tienes que poder separarlos. Por ejemplo con lo que indicas como escenario.

```
create table coches (id int, CódigoMarca int, CódigoGrupo int, CódigoModelo int, descripcion varchar(100))
go
insert into coches (id, CódigoMarca, CódigoGrupo, CódigoModelo, descripcion)
values
(1 ,    1,null  , null  ,'a'),
(2 ,    2,null  , 1     ,'b'),
(3 ,    3,1     , null  ,'c'),
(4 ,null ,null  , 2     ,'d'),
(5 ,null ,null  , 2     ,'e'),
(6 ,null ,1     , null  ,'f'),
(7 ,1    ,null  , 1     ,'g'),
(8 ,null ,null  , null  ,'h'),
(9 ,1    ,1     , null  ,'i'),
(10,1    ,2 , 1     ,'k'),
(11,1    ,2     , null  ,'j'),
(12,1    ,2     , 3     ,'l');

go
```

Y una solución utilizando el operador exists e insertando mediante un xml.nodes (juraría que te es válido para 2008) en una variable tipo tabla

```
declare @CódigoMarca varchar(100) ='1;2'
declare @CódigoGrupo varchar(100) ='1;2';
declare @CódigoModelo varchar(100);
declare @SplitSep varchar(10)=';'

Declare @xml XML;
Declare @tableMarcas table
    (   id int identity(1,1),
        value int
    );
Declare @tableGrupos table
(   id int identity(1,1),
    value int
);
Declare @tableModelos table
(   id int identity(1,1),
    value int
);

SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@CódigoMarca , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @tableMarcas
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
         'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
        FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);

SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@CódigoGrupo , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @tableGrupos
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
         'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
        FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
REPLACE(@CódigoModelo , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') + 
    '</s></r>');
INSERT INTO @tableModelos
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.',
         'varchar(max)')))) AS Value
        FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);


select distinct * from coches 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT T.VALUE 
      FROM @tableMarcas T 
      WHERE T.VAlue = coches.CódigoMarca ) OR @CódigoMarca IS NULL)
      AND 
      (EXISTS (SELECT T.VALUE 
      FROM @tableGrupos T 
      WHERE T.VAlue = coches.CódigoGrupo ) OR @CódigoGrupo IS NULL)
      AND
      (EXISTS (SELECT T.VALUE 
      FROM @tableModelos T 
      WHERE T.VAlue = coches.CódigoModelo ) OR @CódigoModelo IS NULL)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes más opciones documentadas aquí.

[Listas de valores](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/pasar-lista-de-valores-a-un-procedure/)

[Otro enlace más breve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334247/pasar-una-cadena-de-texto-a-un-procedure-para-obtener-datos-cuyos-valores-est%C3%A9n)

Comment: Gracias por la elaborada respuesta, pero no es mi caso. Cuando defines un parámetro en un conjunto de datos de ssrs, se utiliza IN cuando se pueden especificar varios valores. Esto lo he visto hecho así en otros sitios, y está funcionando. El problema me surge cuando especifico "OR @param IS NULL" para poder no especificarlo, porque luego al imprimir el informe es cuando falla.