# Como hacer busqueda insertando multiples registros en text box con sql server

Tags: c#, sql

Les solicito su ayuda para ver si me pueden orientar.

Estoy trabajando sobre una busqueda de registros, la idea es que el usuario a la hora de introducir los datos de busqueda, pueda introducir varios registros y no solo uno en el textbox. Y al introducir multiples registros arroje los datos que correspondan de esa busqueda..

Como en la imagen de muestra que adjunto, del lado izquierdo son ejemplos de todas esas ordenes que se pueden poner en el textbox y posteriormente dar clic en el boton buscar para obtener los registros.. Mas que nada mi duda es como hacer el store procedure y el parametro para que pueda recibir multiples registros. Espero alguien pueda orientarme..

Con un solo registro no tengo problemas, pero mi detalle viene es cuando son multiples

```
DECLARE @Character_Expression VARCHAR(50);
SET @Character_Expression = '7786185-52'; 

SELECT * FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor WHERE Orden=@Character_Expression
```

Saludos..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo no entiendo donde esta tu problema.. en el textbox? en como mandar eso al Procedure? en que escribir en el procedure?

Comment: Hola, en como hacer el store amigo. Las condiciones de los filtros para que le pueda por eje mandar una cadena asi EXEC SPFS_OBTENER_ROTOR_SALDOSMULTPLE '7786185-52  18704397-1  18704844-1' y que me traiga esos tres registros, pero esos 3 se van a poner en un solo textbox. No se si me entiendas hermano.. La idea es que el usuario pueda ingresar varias ordenes en la caja de texto y no buscar uno por uno..

Comment: por ejemplo usando un in y separanado las cadenas que introdujo el usuario con comas?

Comment: Exacto hermano, pero pues ahi no se como hacerlo. Soy nuevo en sql.. Estaba revisando el stuff, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar..

Comment: Pasa la cadena ya transformada y no necesitas saber nada mas que como usar un in para hacerlo. Si no, vas a necesitar un procedimiento que lo haga todo del lado de la base de datos....

Comment: No pues gracias!!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo así: [pasar cadena de texto a un procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334247/pasar-una-cadena-de-texto-a-un-procedure-para-obtener-datos-cuyos-valores-est%c3%a9n)

Comment: Muchas gracias por ese link con ejemplos Javi fer2. Me sirvió bastante darle una leída.. Te agradezco, saludos!!!